# How to solve "No module named 'telepot"' error in Mac

Tags: python, macos, telepot

Hello everybody I'm trying to run the simplest code of tutorial about telepot in python but I keep getting this message
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telepot'

My code is very basic

`import telepot`

`bot = telepot.Bot('1446317719:AAGZy_WVMMv8NG6g_E_fQCyx9ItdIprk7oA')`

`bot.getMe()`

My python version is Python 2.7.16

My python3 version is Python 3.9.0

and my OS is Catalina 10.15.7

I have repeatedly installed telepot with pip install telepot and uninstalled and installed again. It has always completed with no error so I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: which version are you using python2.7 or 3.9

Comment: you should not be using python 2.X, are you sure your env has telepot installed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I installed it using pip3 install telepot and now it works